# How to get sqlite database into Orange?

Tags: orange

I have really liked Orange for the most part, but haven't been able to get it to work with my sqlite data files. I've tried using the SQL Select, but it doesn't seem to take any connect string I pass it:
e.g.
sqlite:///Users/me/test.db/

The correct path to test.db is: /Users/me/test.db

Always see the following error:

AttributeError                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Orange.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Orange/OrangeWidgets/Utilities/OWDatabasesPack.py", line 120, in _error
    u"Error: {0}".format(error.errorString())
AttributeError: 'NetworkError' object has no attribute 'errorString'

### sqlite3:///Users/zach/test.db/

TypeError                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Orange.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Orange/OrangeWidgets/Prototypes/OWSQLSelect.py", line 84, in connectDB
    self.sqlReader.connect(connectString)
  File "/Applications/Orange.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Orange/utils/**init**.py", line 214, in wrap_call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Orange.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Orange/data/sql.py", line 195, in connect
    (self.quirks, self.conn) = _connection(uri)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Do you want [this Orange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(software))?

Comment: That's the Orange I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Orange never supported sqlite.
2. You are using Orange 2, which has been deprecated for some years now.